# ASP.NET.MVC 5 Adding permissions to action of a controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have project with Windows Authentication and with a controller I have a question, by that controller below, I can get information by specifying the name of branch (by typing URL into a browser address bar for example):

"http://localhost:62249/Students/TestNew/Branch1";

And it will display to the user data where branch = Branch1.

Now the question is - how can I achieve the following?

For each branchname I want specify permission to allow open this page by specifying group from ActiveDirectory. Or it's impossible and I should create 10 more controllers and specify there permission for each one.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult TestNew(string branchname)
    {
        // check stuff like permissions
        var db = new MovieContext();
        var model = new Model();


        var students = db.Student
            .Where(x => x.BranchName == branchname)
            .GroupBy(x => new { x.BranchName, x.Name, x.Currency, x.NoCart, x.NoAccount })
            .Select(x => new
            {
                BranchName = x.FirstOrDefault().BranchName,
                Name = x.FirstOrDefault().Name,
                A_Status = x.Max(p => p.A_Status),
                Currency = x.FirstOrDefault().Currency,
                NoCart = x.FirstOrDefault().NoCart,
                NoAccount = x.FirstOrDefault().NoAccount
            }).ToList();
        foreach (var item in students)
        {
            model.Students.Add(new Student
            {
                A_Status = item.A_Status,
                BranchName = item.BranchName,
                Name = item.Name,
                NoAccount = item.NoAccount,
                NoCart = item.NoCart,
                Currency = item.Currency

            });
        }
        return View(model);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Policy based authorization https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-2.1 and use an authorization Handler in your foreach loop to check if current user is allowed to access the ressource.

Here's an example of what I did except that I use groups in my db rather than AD groups :

first you create a requirement it can be emtpy or not depending on your needs, as in Microsoft docs it can contains your group name.

```
 public class CIAssetManagementRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
}
```

Then your Policy, the purpose of this class is to return context.Succeed(requirement); when user is allowed to perform an action :

```
 public class CIAuthoringManagement : AuthorizationHandler<CIAuthoringManagementRequirement, ConfigurationItem>
{
    private readonly MyAppContext _context;

    public CIAuthoringManagement(MyAppContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, CIAuthoringManagementRequirement requirement, ConfigurationItem resource)
    {
        var user = _context.Users.Include(u => u.Groups).Include(u => u.Employer).Include(c => c.AuthoringCatalogs).AsNoTracking().SingleOrDefault(m => m.ID == context.User.GetUniqueIdentifier());

        if (user != null)
        {
            //Allowing SuperAdmins by default
            var group = _context.Groups.Include(g => g.Users).ThenInclude(g => g.User).AsNoTracking().SingleOrDefault(g => g.DisplayName == "SuperAdmins");
            if (group != null)
            {
                var groupUsers = new HashSet<Guid>(group.Users.Select(u => u.User.ID));
                if (groupUsers.Contains(user.ID))
                {
                    context.Succeed(requirement);
                }
            }

            //Allowing CI if it's part of the catalogs where CI is author
            //hashset of id where user is declared author
            var authorCatalogHS = new HashSet<Guid>(user.AuthoringCatalogs.Select(c => c.CatalogId));

            if (resource.Catalogs != null)
            {
                foreach (var catalog in resource.Catalogs)
                {
                    if (authorCatalogHS.Contains(catalog.CatalogId))
                    {
                        context.Succeed(requirement);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
                context.Succeed(requirement);

        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

You instanciate your Policy in your startup :

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            // require user to have cookie auth or jwt bearer token
            options.AddPolicy("Authenticated",
                policy => policy
                    .AddAuthenticationSchemes(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser());
                              options.AddPolicy("CIAuthoringManagement",
                policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new CIAuthoringManagementRequirement()));

                       });
services.AddTransient<IAuthorizationHandler, CIAuthoringManagement>();
```

And finally in your controller :

```
foreach (var ciApplication in _context.CIApplications.AsNoTracking())
                    {
                        if ((await _authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(User, ciApplication, "CIAuthoringManagement")).Succeeded)
                        {

                            CIApplications.Add(ciApplication);
                        }
                    }
return CIApplications;
```

Comment: I'm not using an ASP.NET CORE or it's also possible in ASP.NET MVC 5?

Comment: I haven't tried but this project brings policies to MVC 5. https://github.com/pschaeflein/mvc5-authorization-policy